# How to resolve: SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```js
else if(command=='quote')
  {
    let getQuote=async() => 
    {
      let result= await fetch('<api>')
      let json = await result.json()
      return json
    }
    let quote = await getQuote()
    message.channel.send(quote);
  }
```

I am getting error at `let quote = await getQuote()` as

> SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

How to solve this?

Comment: The function `await getQuote()` is in needs to be an async function.

Comment: trigger the   getQuote() function without await keyword  let quote =  getQuote() and  you used like quote.then(console.log)   or  wrap it inside async function

Answer (score 1):

Think about the scope. Your second "await" is out of the scope of the async function. I mean following code part should put in the scope of the async function.

```js
let quote = await getQuote()
    message.channel.send(quote);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrapper the code with IIFE ,so in your example

```
else if(command=='quote')
  {
(async() => {
    let getQuote=async() => 
    {
      let result= await fetch('<api>')
      let json = await result.json()
      return json
    }
    let quote = await getQuote()
    message.channel.send(quote);
    })()
  }
```

or I recommended

```
else if(command=='quote')
  {
    let getQuote=async() => 
    {
      let result= await fetch('<api>')
      let json = await result.json()
      return json
    }

    getQuote().then(quote=>{message.channel.send(quote)});
  }
```